# how to work duplicate values delete from query

Tags: sql, oracle11g

This is my query....

```
delete from
   second_salary a
 where 
   a.rowid > any (
       select b.rowid 
         from second_salary b
        where a.salary = b.salary)
```

can any one explain this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### sql 1:

> delete from second_salary a where a.rowid > any (**sql 2**)

Browse **each** record in the table **second_salary**, if record have **rowid** > any value in array result of sql 2 then delete it.

### sql 2:

(with a.salary is a number knew form a record is reviewed, example N)

> select b.rowid from second_salary b where a.salary = b.salary

Result return: a array rowid of records have **N = b.salary**

End: retain a record have smalless rowid in records have salary simalar.